# Overriding a method overrides parent annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

Does overriding a method override parent annotations? For instance:

```
public interface CustomRepository {
    @Cacheable("top10UsersCache")
    List<User> getTop10Users();
}

interface CustomFeignRepository extends CustomRepository {
    @Override
    @GetMapping("top10Users")
    List<User> getTop10Users(); 
}
```

Method `getTop10Users()` (from Feign repository) it is still cacheable?

Comment: Note that `@Inherited` has no effect on method annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To inherit method / class annotations, the annotation itself must be annotated `@Inherited`
.

Comment: From the documentation of [`@Inherited`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html): "_Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated type is used to annotate anything other than a class. Note also that this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be inherited from superclasses; annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect_". In other words, it has no effect on method annotations. If Spring defines its own semantics then this answer should quote the relevant documentation.